# Who pays the fee on a NYC no-fee co-broke apartment rental?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, broker, new-york

I know the following is true (or if it's not, please correct me!):

a) If my broker shows me a place that has a fee that's listed by another broker, then they split the fee (i.e. a typcial co-broke situation - I pay 15% and they each get 7.5%).

b) If I see a place that is no fee, and I see it with the listing broker, then the landlord pays the fee, and I pay nothing (i.e. a typical no-fee situation).

c) If I see a place that is *not* listed by a broker (i.e. it has its own leasing office) on my own, then I pay no fee.  But if I see it with my broker, then I have to pay a fee to my broker.

What if I see a place with my broker, that is listed by another broker, and is no-fee?  Do I pay anything to my broker (7.5%? 15%?) Or does the landlord pay 7.5% to my broker and 7.5% to the listing broker like the situation described in "a" above?

Comment: What, if anything, did you sign with your broker?

Answer (score 1):

I think "no fee" means the landlord pays the fees to both brokers (which is usually the case in NYC suburbs but not in the city itself). In your case 7.5% to each broker. Most likely if you see that apartment without the broker then the listing broker will keep entire 15%.

Answer (score 0):

What's common nowadays is CYOF - or "Collect your own fee". This normally means a place that's listed as "no fee" because the listing agent is being paid by the person who owns the apartment regardless once they rent it. CYOF is telling other agents/brokers that if they show this apartment they need to negotiate a fee agreement outside of the rental because the listing agent will not be splitting a portion of their fee.